# Trouble with permutations and combinations problems

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am having problems with the topic permutations and combinations. Even after a lot of practice I'm making some basic mistakes but I don't know how to fix them. The main problem is overlapping or missing to count some permutations. The link to some of the questions I have made errors in are given below:

[The number of 3 digit numbers of the form xyz such that $x<y$ and $z\leq y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171143/the-number-of-3-digit-numbers-of-the-form-xyz-such-that-xy-and-z-leq-y/2171162#2171162)

[A team of 11 players with at least 3 bowlers and 1 wicket keeper is to be formed from 16 players; 4 are bowlers; 2 are wicket keepers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168055/a-team-of-11-players-with-at-least-3-bowlers-and-1-wicket-keeper-is-to-be-formed)

[In how many ways can we give 5 apples 4 mangoes 3 oranges to 3 people if each may receive none, one or more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161696/in-how-many-ways-can-we-give-5-apples-4-mangoes-3-oranges-to-3-people-if-each-ma)

I really need to know how I can avoid these mistakes and ensure I get the right answer. It would be great if someone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: The best *short* piece of advice I can give, when using multiplication principle make sure your steps will produce 1) *Every* outcome at least once and 2) Every outcome *at most once*.  Run through your steps building a test example and ask yourself if you can run through the steps a different way to get the same outcome.  If you can, then you probably overcounted.  If everything was overcounted the exact same amount, the method could still be salvagable by dividing by symmetry, but otherwise you might have to try a different approach.  Spotting errors becomes easier with practice.

Comment: It helps also to see several examples of problems and the tools used in solving them.  As you see more and more examples in the future when you are given a new problem one of the first things you should try to do is see if it can be reworded in such a way that it is analogous to a problem you've already seen before just with different numbers and flavor.  That being said, don't just memorize problems, but instead learn the techniques themselves.  It helps also to see *wrong* answers (*that you know are wrong*) to see why they are incorrect so you can hopefully avoid making those same mistakes.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, I'll surely work on these points. Please add any more points that come to your mind. Thank you!